# jquery ajax problems

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone help me with the following code? The second ajax call is never been reached. What am i doing wrong?

```
      $('a').click(function(){
      var url1 = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: url1,
            sucess: function(data){
                var content = $('div[title="categorii"]', data).html();
                alert ("success1");
                $('a',content).click(function(){
                    alert ("ajax2");
                   var url2 = $(this).attr('href');
                   $.ajax({
                       url: url2,
                       success: function(data1){
                           var content2 = $('div[title="categorii"]', data1).html();
                           $('div[title="categorii"]').html(content2);
                       }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                $('div[title]').html(content);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean it isn't reached?  All the code does is add an event handler that will call `ajax` when clicked. It will not call your second ajax method without being clicked.

Call the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method if you want to fire the event handler attached with `click(handler)`

Comment: ok. if i press any <a> on the page that is loaded with first ajax, it doesn't work.